# TS strict paths with dot notation in array

Tags: typescript

Trying to make the `populate` parameter in [MikroORM](https://github.com/mikro-orm/mikro-orm) strict for the variant with string paths. I managed to implement (more like adjust the one I found on TS discord) the `AuthPath` type that works based on my needs. It works ok when used with a single parameter, but when used with array, it won't validate correctly if one of the array items is valid.

So the question is, how can I make it work with arrays? Is it even possible? I was trying to use tuple types to get around this, but failed to make it work. I kinda understand the problem is the shared generic type `P` - I am planning to leverage it in the return type so I need something to bare the actual (inferred) types in the signature from params to return type.

The full playground in [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCD2IQFNgBcCW8B2AeAKgHzQDe0GayAthAPwBc0+A2gLrQC+AUKJDAErIAZsgBOybMGQFiZCtQZNOXLmgCeAB2TQAQvHgBraAF5SXaOQAmjCGlEZsAcwA056JjQobdhy7dgAVzQAC3hRRgBVCDFXC3EhAEZGQRFxSWkosUJXblVNbUzREzMLDGtoW3snWOhsMCpkbyq-CzBHRtqAqgAjGLchewlywpqBjCGIRgQkVEwcXELst279A0m4RBR0LDw9QyXc9S1oAFEADzswdHx8mWL8aGQLiY2Z7fmHVOgI4lpv6EYAAoHk9KNhLAJhGIJFJcJ8xN9fv9GPgAJR5Y4AZR8TgA0sg1BA7qYQc9wTBpls5ngwNg1MQ3H8AAYAEhI51AAUs0gMBPgQlOF1EVzQNy0MmcFTUPUQhA4TOgbhRjzJEOgKWh6VwtPpbgszLZHJAXJ5fIF50u11uRElEGlKxAcoVeoB0FZ7LOnO5uF5an5TFt9tl8ox2gA4sg0Njmvi1ARJbiVWC1dHfLGiURiKZE6CXr7-Q8-hbhVbxSxcaxiIxsMgAG5iFRHbQAQSC8AACmAQrgAPKS9tJl6VXxZtyAgcAMjdbOHTg4ADoFbnybU6wi-gPGJPpyRZ44F0zUYOV-CigBFF1-M-HtXu0-QZsLtn3nQhizv6B-Zs3mCpvEEoke0IF0PwNEhH3nNlWzQDsu2CXAIyjHFHFjXtJWbbJdCdED32rNdRBwxhr2XFNkPTXtgI-UDoEBRC-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-aHpjz6glCUQJbZv3-fIAUeO0MBLEsY3Faz3X1u1rtyBgWswBAMoVfBYfte0DH4CNlB6xASV84WpBoCoMBeTW6B0qgGuI-dxmG6b16W5CMIO8bg6fcdoA).

Here is the demonstration of the problem:

```
declare const user: User;
declare function get1<O, P extends string>(obj: O, path: AutoPath<O, P>): void;
declare function get2<O, P extends string>(obj: O, path: AutoPath<O, P>[]): void;

// works fine with single item
get1(user, "friend.books.title")
get1(user, "friend.books.ref1.age")
get1(user, "friend.friend.name")
// @ts-expect-error
get1(user, "friend.friend.www")
// @ts-expect-error
get1(user, "friend.books.www")
// @ts-expect-error
get1(user, "friend.books.ref1.www")

// works fine with array when there is just one item
get2(user, ["friend.name"])
get2(user, ["friend.books.ref1.age"])
// @ts-expect-error
get2(user, ["friend.books.ref1.www"])

// if there are more items it works only sometimes
// @ts-expect-error
get2(user, ["friend.name", "books.author.www"])

// if we add one more item that is valid and on the root level, it will make it pass
get2(user, ["friend.name", "books.author.www", "age"])
```

Here is the code for `AutoPath` and the entity type definitions:

```
class Collection<T> { items?: T[] }
class Reference<T> { item?: T }

type Book = {
  id: string,
  title: string,
  author: User,
  ref1: Reference<User>,
}

type User = {
  id: string,
  name: string,
  age: number,
  friend: User,
  friends: Collection<User>,
  books: Collection<Book>,
}

type ExtractType<T> = T extends Collection<infer U> ? U : (T extends Reference<infer U> ? U : T)
type StringKeys<T> = T extends Collection<any> 
  ? `${Exclude<keyof ExtractType<T>, symbol>}` 
  : T extends Reference<any>
    ? `${Exclude<keyof ExtractType<T>, symbol>}` 
    : `${Exclude<keyof T, symbol>}`
type GetStringKey<T, K extends StringKeys<T>> = K extends keyof T ? ExtractType<T[K]> : never

type AutoPath<O, P extends string> =
  (P & `${string}.` extends never ? P : P & `${string}.`) extends infer Q
    ? Q extends `${infer A}.${infer B}`
      ? A extends StringKeys<O>
        ? `${A}.${AutoPath<GetStringKey<O, A>, B>}`
        : never
      : Q extends StringKeys<O>
        ? (GetStringKey<O, Q> extends unknown ? Exclude<P, `${string}.`> : never) | (StringKeys<GetStringKey<O, Q>> extends never ? never : `${Q}.`)
        : StringKeys<O>
    : never
```

(the `AutoPath` type still has some issues, but that is not really important - this question is about how to use it with array of strings instead of a single string parameter)

Comment: Why `"books.author.www"` is valid?

Comment: It is not supposed to be valid. I forgot one expect-error comment at the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I *think* the issue here is that you  want `AutoPath<O, P>` to *distribute* over unions in `P`.  That is, you want `AutoPath<O, P1 | P2>` to be equivalent to `AutoPath<O, P1> | AutoPath<O, P2>`.  And sometimes it does not seem to work out that way.

If so, then you can use [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) to get this behavior.  All you need to do is wrap your original definition with `P extends any ? ... : never`:

```
type AutoPath<O, P extends string> =
  P extends any ?
  /* ORIGINAL IMPLEMENTATION */
  (P & `${string}.` extends never ? P : P & `${string}.`) extends infer Q
  ? Q extends `${infer A}.${infer B}`
  ? A extends StringKeys<O>
  ? `${A}.${AutoPath<GetStringKey<O, A>, B>}`
  : never
  : Q extends StringKeys<O>
  ? (GetStringKey<O, Q> extends unknown ? Exclude<P, `${string}.`> : never) | (StringKeys<GetStringKey<O, Q>> extends never ? never : `${Q}.`)
  : StringKeys<O>
  : never
  /* END ORIGINAL IMPLEMENTATION */
  : never
```

And you should hopefully get the behavior you want:

```
get2(user, ["friend.name", "books.author.www", "age"]); // error!
// ----------------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

It's always possible that some inference or other behavior you were relying on will be altered by this change, but because the particular implementation of `AutoPath` and what it's being used for is out of scope for the question, I'll leave it up to you to deal with any such issues.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCD2IQFNgBcCW8B2AeAKgHzQDe0GayAthAPwBc0+A2gLrQC+AUKJDAErIAZsgBOybMGQFiZCtQZNOXLmgCeAB2TQAQvHgBraAF5SXaOQAmjCGlEZsAcwA056JjQobdhy7dgAVzQAC3hRRgBVCDFXC3EhAEZGQRFxSWkosUJXblVNbUzREzMLDGtoW3snWOhsMCpkbyq-CzBHRtqAqgAjGLchewlywpqBjCGIRgQkVEwcXELst279A0m4RBR0LDw9QyXc9S1oAFEADzswdHx8mWL8aGQLiY2Z7fmHVOgI4lpv6EYAAoHk9KNhLAJhGIJFJcJ8xN9fv9GPgAJR5Y4AZR8TgA0sg1BA7qYQc9wTBpls5ngwNg1IQ3H8AAYAEhI51AAUs0gMBPgQlOF1EVzQNy0MmcFTUPUQhA4TLcKMeZIh0BS0PSuFp9MZ0FZ7LOnO5uF5an5gsu11uRElEGlKxAcoVFkY+o5IC5PL5AvwtvtsvlGO0AHFkGhsc18WoCJLccqwaqI74o0SiMRTHHQS9TeaHn9zpbRdbmLjWMRGNhkAA3MQqI7aACCQXgAAUwCFcAB5SUt+MvSq+dNuXtZ8nQbXQWhuQG9gBkerZA6cHAAdEy+2PKzWin9e4w5wuSEvHKumaiN6r4UUAIq668XmD6q-QBurtnPnSBix-BsP6BJvECSJTsGW-Q9XxXNkmzQVt22CXBQ3DHFHCjLtJQbbJdCdRVamrWsXWge9R0TZCUy7UDJ2gQFEIAlCCTQwjiGImAAmwAxsHgAB3bBKPdT1cBbSV9WPU9y1w7dzwAHyo2iyJo0j6O7RimJVGAtwRP51KKV02WvU90QI2SgPInCtNMvDRBUbleHEaBgBwWxoACaJwm+FyAG4uGs8BbKEVj3h49o0ASBiR1UipkMIQF4G6AArRglI0ODGGg2COyUltCFRRgq3gMpPO8sBfP86loCCgAmUK-2PKKYvi6BEuSl9mzbdKe0INhsugXL8pUAB6ProE4sI1mgIQHG0TiKGCCpfBQchKCoLggoSQFnJiaAACIxiGFcVkMCAVw8FBNvRFa1pcyVtsGcE9tWQ74gSFc2mQU7lrDVb1tEK6dtu37LBXOoGjegboAAATQCAAFoni0dAYdEUQwne4KLo267xj+m6Ac43GQcGiHodh2YEaRyzzq+n7sbug6V1xzj8fByGYbOOG0FJ5GKcurb-pptYV0eum8fRLhQeG0RRvGyshum8dEbANQhuCCR3GV2yMBgWLnLQaAcG0eQloqtHvugZgMd2oHXtYM6w3K43JTN3n9v5wWXs263RYJ5nifhsQyZRu3KdN83budh7hCe+n3ZF0GMAFEJoTl7QqDCfXFpgCghpGmAcBARWIHgBpMAaCAA-t4PectzarrD56glCUQhYZj3PfIAVOO0MBLEsXXpZT9XFtV9tyBgKswBAMpx3BXvVe0JH4B1lAaxASVM6mpBoCoMBeQW6AkqgMug8d6mq5r+665CMIm+rra3et9zoFBv2wgAQlbqGP8-r-v5-qHiAAP0AUA4BICgEqC4EAA)

Comment: Wow, thanks, I would have never though about something like that! Looks like it helps. If I may, I have one more small issue with that code - it also accepts internal methods on string/number/scalar prototypes, so `friend.name.charAt` is still valid - do you have an idea how to get around that? I guess I will need to blacklist types that I do not want to be expanded somewhere.

Comment: While I'm happy to help, that is outside the scope of the question (I don't see it mentioned anywhere; it was true of your original code and not just my solution; and adding it to this question now would be a fairly sizable scope creep) and comments are not a great place to answer separate questions.  My guess is that you can only expand types that extend `object`, which would prohibit primitives like `string`/`number` without explicit blacklisting...

Comment: Would this also work to type [lodash get](https://lodash.com/docs/#get)?

Comment: @jcalz Hi there, added a follow up question about mapping this information to the return type, would be great if you could take a look, thanks in advance! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68454737/mapping-of-strict-path-notation-array-type