# Enhancing type of object properties based on type parameter

Tags: typescript

I want to enhance return type of a function based on a type parameter.

Let's say I have entity with property `ref1` of type `Reference<User>`, and based on the type parameter I want to enhance it to `LoadedReference<User>` if `ref1` (or `ref1.something`, or `ref1.something.something`...) is part of the type parameter value.

The demonstration of this problem follows:

```
// T1 is what I want for all of those
type T1 = LoadedIfInKeyHint<Book, 'ref1', 'ref1.books'>
// T2 is the problem, as it resolves to a union
type T2 = LoadedIfInKeyHint<Book, 'ref1', 'ref1' | 'ref1.books'>
// T3 demonstrates that the problem is just with having both `ref1` and `ref1.books` in the input type
type T3 = LoadedIfInKeyHint<Book, 'ref1', 'ref1.books' | 'title' | 'id'>

declare const t1: T1;
declare const t2: T2;
declare const t3: T3;
console.log(t1.$.books.$[0].title) // works as expected
console.log(t2.$.books.$[0].title) // does not work as `books` resolves to union
console.log(t3.$.books.$[0].title) // works as expected
```

`LoadedIfInKeyHint` type is used to resolve the type of object properties. It is used recursively via the `Loaded` type. Their definition follows:

```
type MarkLoaded<T, P, H = unknown> = P extends Reference<infer U>
  ? LoadedReference<U, Loaded<U, H>>
  : P extends Collection<infer U>
    ? LoadedCollection<U, Loaded<U, H>>
    : T;

type LoadedIfInKeyHint<T, K extends keyof T, H> = H extends `${infer A}.${infer B}`
    ? A extends K
      ? MarkLoaded<T, T[A], B> 
      : never
    : K extends H 
    ? MarkLoaded<T, T[K]>
  : never;

export type Loaded<T, P = unknown> = unknown extends P ? T : T & Simplify<{
  [K in keyof RelationsIn<T>]: LoadedIfInKeyHint<T, K, P>;
}>
```

(the `Simplify` type just removes properties that would resolve to `never`)

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCD2IQFNgBcCW8B2AeAKgHzQDe0GayAthAPwBc0+A2gLrQC+AUKJDAErIAZsgBOybMGQFiZCtQZNOXLmgCeAB2TQAQvHgBraAF5SXaOQAmjCGlEZsAcwA056JjQobdhy7dgAVzQAC3hRRgBVCDFXC3EhAEZGQRFxSWkosUJXblVNbUzREzMLDGtoW3snWOhsMCpkbyq-CzBHRtqAqgAjGLchewlywpqBjCGIRgQkVEwcXELst279A0m4RBR0LDw9QyXc5AAPDTC0cmxKUSEwKWgAGXgwS2RLFLEJKQJnaAAFYuwyAAblloMdKNhLAJhB90jIStAACSMfDQABkfwA3G52mgABQAShR6KxXEOJzOFyuNzuj2er2mWzmeHwP3+pkBINExHBEw2M228yICOR0HEzxwIDU0DxqIxvwJbGxFlxhMY4sskulspJCqVZJU6i00AAsmBRAY6S9LN8-j8ABLFALYAzYeAAd2wxFM-15kOhqU+0gcqWgEUIbloDye1veaS+ER+VteCwdhAjFkYvqOEKh-KZO1wIbEYYzFmgUeTlkZs0Liej9Jt9ft6bcmaY2LyxqrAEkhD3sABpZBqe0ONC2wdgnN8gwj+BCJhp4qOv15gAGiJIxaKAEEOAA6Lc73QcddtivQXfT3MwQcXixRs0Wqu2li71g-HTEB-QRicsQL0YKc1xgR0Lyfc1LRjFNWSYZhB1YMt-2BMROwAenQpgEnIGB3WCMBzh7aB3TAS5oCEMJoDAJBoAXdxQmiLttHwHDTF7fshxHMdLlwPYDB+AByeIEkEoSRIPFZDAgQSI0wpgACZcIY7QNFEeBuhQKgfkgchznECBEBBGA0HgajoGdHZmMU4oOIHYdR3HPjVnE4RRNcxJBOgAAfaBhLcyTVhkuSsPwABmaAXioHBKkI5ATII84QlU9TNOoZSACsAlsEiKGCaACKBXxoBWEJoHXET12oyFyokqS1iqhwVIuDQgncfJrPC2yYMsPt7O4pz+I89y-LqoKvN8wSPBQCa-LKWSVBeXhxGgYAYqSpJsOxJbwBWtbsBytAFJRBTttQXbtH2w6wpRMLsSuxBkAPEB4EcPE0ASI9Auko9mAABlYA9puQAloHk90wjWaiYGOLR0FeHgYse57XvehSvvqiBfoBoGKBQUH5M1eLangc4IYtaHysxqqDKM4nTIs7ArIelAUbetAwoxoLscB4GCaw8mod02HZgRrh5OCNA0A0SZMIaSwMC6A81qodDLDADApQyiB0KNeLgHsDQ0AAWgN5A4uNsBTZwBXmWN7pIFeY2IACbpohNvWIGNgBOSxvb+hSpDAABWboAA5gGsgBlV38HyW1YG9P4MGAAxbTIBCLmgOc1Ho-BWBRBD2FAuBLynFCuU4Zgc7zpDOz16BBHAZkIAHeFTBj7o460BPNlreYyLUYhfLjINcEH4fGZeIQHFeQhsQbgBRI5QACF4ADlUNEScb1nedF2FUwWEQ3f-VqLfLwAopgMNfJoCjjAqA0EAMCENR29IaBM6amuD8p5fV4by3pOQgBd4In3JKcUQSU76vjguyRmroPReidC6N0npT55n+FGVExIMQPyfi-N+uASBuG-tgbO+9G7IGbjsVuLJQGMDslxRyvE4KDjZPPMkEYgA) that should not produce any errors.

(Follow up to [Mapping of strict path notation array type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68454737/mapping-of-strict-path-notation-array-type) question that describes the end goal.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that here:

```
type T2 = LoadedIfInKeyHint<Book, 'ref1', 'ref1' | 'ref1.books'>
```

The problem is that it resolves to something like:

```
type T2 =
  LoadedReference<User, User & Simplify<{
    friends: LoadedCollection<User, User>;
    books: never;
  }>>
  | LoadedReference<User, User & Simplify<{
    friends: never
    books: LoadedCollection<User, User>;
  }>>
```

That could be fixed [by converting the union to intersection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286/1236795):

```
type UnionToIntersection<U> = 
  (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never

type FixedLoadedIfInKeyHint<T, K extends keyof T, H> = UnionToIntersection<LoadedIfInKeyHint<T, K, H>>;
```

Oh, and a [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCD2IQFNgBcCW8B2AeAKgHzQDe0GayAthAPwBc0+A2gLrQC+AUKJDAErIAZsgBOybMGQFiZCtQZNOXLmgCeAB2TQAQvHgBraAF5SXaOQAmjCGlEZsAcwA056JjQobdhy7dgAVzQAC3hRRgBVCDFXC3EhAEZGQRFxSWkosUJXblVNbUzREzMLDGtoW3snWOhsMCpkbyq-CzBHRtqAqgAjGLchewlywpqBjCGIRgQkVEwcXELst279A0m4RBR0LDw9QyXc5AAPDTC0cmxKUSEwKWgAGXgwS2RLFLEJKQJnaAAFYuwyAAblloMdKNhLAJhB90jIStAACSMfDQABkfwA3G52mgABQAShR6KxXEOJzOFyuNzuj2er2mWzmeHwP3+pkBINExHBEw2M228yICOR0HEzxwIDU0DxqIxvwJbGxFlxhMY4sskulspJCqVZJU6i00AAsmBRAY6S9LN8-j8ABLFALYAzYeAAd2wxFM-15kOhqU+0gcqWgEUIbloDye1veaS+ER+VteCwdhAjFkYvqOEKh-KZO1wIbEYYzFmgUeTlkZs0Liej9Jt9ft6bcmaY2LyxqrAEkhD3sABpZBqe0ONC2wdgnN8gwj+BCJhp4qOv15gAGiJIxaKAEEOAA6Lc73QcddtivQXfT3MwQcXixRs0Wqu2li71g-HTEB-QRicsQL0YKc1xgR0Lyfc1LRjFNWSYZhB1YMt-2BMROyNApsB2fB4AHK5okFPBw2KNw8QiG8+TAbBpSjPEDEiAkTGIIF4DKP9alQ0RGNAmU6MYE8e0Y4xmNYyxGKjHt2IA0RDXyaAADEMCOV5e37IcRzHS5Jwo-1oDnNQFyXaAW2KCIsJwHC8LEAjmVwVSB2HUdx0nNNCE7AB6dymAScgYHdYIwHOST3So84hDCaAwCQaBDJCeBoi7bR8B80xFOUyx7PUpytL2AwfgAcniBJ8oKoqDxWQwIHyiNPKYAAmXz3GCbQNFEeBuhQKgfkgchznECBEBBGA0HgSLoGdHZEvq4o0pUmDLD7ByNOc3LSuEYq1sSfLoAAH2gQr1vK1Yqpqrz8AAZmgF4qBwSpAuQYaAvOEIWrajrqEagArAJbGgd0KGCaAAqBXxoBWEJoHXIr10iyFIbKiq1hhhwmu0BwNCCdx8imi6ZqUubG0WrLNInVb9qKkrycOxGqt2-aPBQba9vyspqpUF5eHEaBgFu56km87EOfALmeewX60DqlE6sF1Bhe0UXxfOlFzuxBXEGQA8QHgRw8TQBIjyOyqj2YAAGVgDwZ5BGNq90wjWSKYGOLR0FeHhbvVzXtd1uqDZp42zYtigUGtrzbYtPyAYU-GMvmonHJJt2xY9rWdbQc7feO-3zctkO-rtmAeqd2ZXa4WrgjQNANEmTyGksDAugPHmqHcywwAwKVPogdyMIgYB7A0NAAFo++Qe7B7AYecDr5lB+6SBXkHiAAm6aIh57weAE5LA3k26qkMAAFZugADmAKaAGVl-wfJbVgb0-gwYADFtMgEIuPT50XfBWBRBD2B42Al4pwoS5JwZg+lDLfzcrJY0ghwDMggAOeEphL7dGvloW+mxazzComoYge04xBlwLg-B41ITCAcK8aBGFoAAFEjigACC8AAcpxbSPEIFf3viwRCOk8zSUvAI4CMDtDnwwFQDQIAMBCDUMg0g0A34o04UoHq9DGEsLYXBQchAf7wV4eSU4ohnpyVfHBdkZDXQei9E6F0bpPR8JgP8KMqJiQYjERIqRMjcAkDcIo7AH8DKLjgYFHYiCWQ6MYLNGOhM1Lx2clotk0COARiAA).

Note that I didn't look at the possibility of avoiding the union in the first place, I'm not sure whether that's possible or not.

---

A few things I noticed, not sure if I'm right about them or what's their context.

This may be just a strange example in the playground – I noticed you're using the following line:

```
// T3 demonstrates that the problem is just with having both `ref1` and `ref1.books` in the input type
type T3 = LoadedIfInKeyHint<Book, 'ref1', 'ref1.books' | 'title' | 'id'>
```

But the `title` and `id` part will have no effect. Looking at your type definition of `LoadedIfInKeyHint`:

```
type LoadedIfInKeyHint<T, K extends keyof T, H> = H extends `${infer A}.${infer B}`
    ? (A extends K ? MarkLoaded<T, T[A], B> : never) // 1st branch
    : (K extends H ? MarkLoaded<T, T[K]> : never);   // 2nd branch
```

We can see that those will go to the `2nd branch` which only looks if `ref1` exists in the listed property names (and if so, it marks the property loaded).

Also, looking at the current `MarkLoaded<T, P, H = unknown>` I wonder whether `T` is of any use (it's returned when `P` is neither reference nor a collection, which seems a bit strange to me). Wouldn't dropping paraeter `T` and using `never` do the same job?

```
type MarkLoaded<P, H = unknown> = P extends Reference<infer U>
  ? LoadedReference<U, Loaded<U, H>>
  : P extends Collection<infer U> ? LoadedCollection<U, Loaded<U, H>> : never; // here "never"
```